# how to do Jquery each function or for loop with synchronous process while calling sqlite(Local) database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, local-storage

I am using local database,
Here i am fetching some problem while using each function or for loop to make a call to get data from local database, 
Its not looking like synchronous 
before getting First data All iteration has finished

**I am expecting each iteration should wait until i get data from Local Datbase
How I can active this in java script**
Pl Answer my question

```
var printArray = [];
$.each(list, function(key,val) {
    var tableName = val.tableName;
    var columnName = val.columnName;
    var lineNumber = val.lineNumber;
    var lableName = val.lableName;
    var lableValue = val.lableName;
    var positionLabel = val.positionLabel;
    var positionValue = val.positionValue;

    var query = new ****.Query();
    query.equalTo('Customer_ID','A5F38467-0C64-E411-B51C-005056B57717');

    var tableData = synObj.getOfflineData(tableName,query);
    tableData.then(function(data){
        var jsonValue = {
                            "lineNumber": lineNumber,
                            "lableName": lableName,
                            "lableValue": data[0].columnName,
                            "positionLabel": positionLabel,
                            "positionValue": positionValue,
                        };
         printArray.push(jsonValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried, one simple solution is to use async library, another way is to call a recursive function

Comment: No, you cannot use a synchronous loop. What are looking for is a way to loop asynchronous. Look into promises, post your code (you can [edit] your question), then we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have added some sample code as you asked